# Is it possible in playwright to check things betwen request fired and reponse recived?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright

I am looking for solution to this code, I would like to check between the request fire and response recive to check if clicked button is disabled, like code above but its look unstable

```
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForRequest("**/myEndpoint"),
  myButton.click()
])
await expect(myButton).toBeDisabled();
await page.waitForResponse("**/myEndpoint");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in more linear way like below:

```
await expect(myButton).toBeEnabled()
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForRequest("**/myEndpoint"),
  expect(myButton).toBeDisabled(),
  page.waitForResponse("**/myEndpoint"),
  myButton.click()
])
```